Couple match in google sheet
so I want to match couple in google sheet. Such that...

Here, the XYZ and PQR are a match because both have written their names for each other.
I wrote a formula, but it seems it is incorrect:
=ArrayFormula(if(D2:D278+F2:F278)=(F2:F278+D2:D278),"Match")


Here's one way:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A="")+(B2:B=""),,
   IF(COUNTIF(A2:A&B2:B,B2:B&A2:A),,"No ")&"Match"))



Another option :
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2:B&A2:A;A2:A&B2:B;0));"No Match";"Match"));COUNTA(A2:A);1)


